# Doctrine2 MariaDB integration

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, mariadb

Recent events are moving away developers from MySQL to alternatives such as MariaDB. (It seems I'm one of them).

how painful is the migration and further support Doctrine2 is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB is direct replacement for MySQL *at the same version level*

So there is no MySQL 5.5 equivalent yet.

See the [MariaDB KnowledgeBase](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/mariadb-versus-mysql-compatibility)

Comment: It looks as if it were equal to MySQL... thanks i'll test when I finish the current project